# Are linear combinations of vectors that form a basis still a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

V is a subspace of $R^n$ and $B={u,v,w}$ is a basis for V and

$x = 2u-3v+w$

$y = u+v$

$z = -v-w$

Explain why ${x,y,z}$ are a basis for V

Can I say that:
Any linear combinations of vectors that form a basis are still a basis?

Comment: not all linear combinations of a basis is a basis. for example $x = 2u-3v+w, y = u+v, z = 3u-2v+w$ is not a basis as the last vector in the set is the sum of the first two.

Comment: But in this case it is right?

Comment: yes. in this case $\{x, y, z\}$ is a basis because it is linearly independent.

Comment: Is there a way to show it? A proof so to speak

Comment: *All* vectors in the space are a linear combination of vectors that form a basis, by the definition of basis. Clearly not all possible sets of vectors form a basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can see that $$\pmatrix{x\\y\\z} = \pmatrix{2&-3&1\\1&1&0\\0&-1&-1}
\pmatrix{u\\v\\w}$$ and you need to show that the coefficient matrix in invertible. you can do that either by row reducing it see that you have three pivots or you could find the determinant not zero.

Comment: How to understand the operation in right hand side of your equation as $u,v$ and $w$ are already vectors in $\Bbb R^3$?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the elementary approach:

You want to show that $x,y,z$ are linearly independent, so assume
$$ \lambda x + \mu y + \nu z = 0$$
for some scalars $\lambda, \mu, \nu$ and conclude that $\lambda=\mu=\nu=0$.

Substitute your knowledge about $x,y,z$ into the equation to get
\begin{align*}
0 &= \lambda x + \mu y + \nu z \\
  &= \lambda (2u - 3v + w)
 + \mu (u+v) + \nu (-v-w) \\
&= (2\lambda + \mu) u + (-3\lambda+\mu-\nu)v + (\lambda-\nu)w.
\end{align*}
Since $u,v,w$ are linearly independent we conclude that
\begin{align*}
2\lambda + \mu &= 0, \\
-3\lambda+\mu-\nu &= 0, \\
\lambda - \nu &= 0.
\end{align*}
Solving this linear system of equations yields the unique solution $\lambda=\mu=\nu=0$, so $x,y,z$ are linearly independent.

Answer (score -1):

No. Consider the linear combination of the canonical basis (0,1)+(1,0) and (1,0)+(0,1). They are linearly dependent and hence do not form a basis for R^2